# ERROR : make sure that the maximum index on a list is less than the list size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is my code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string to_date = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Console.WriteLine("a");
       string[] name = new string[3] {"015", "017", "005"};

        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
          {
               Console.WriteLine("The name is  "+ name[i]);
                 conairdata(to_date, name[4]);
          }

            label9.Text = " Now processing... Please wait";
            label9.Refresh();
            Console.WriteLine("d");
    }

    public void conairdata(string to_date , string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("e");
        string path = "H:\\St\\Con\\TB\\mdata"+name+".rpt";
        // nofcol and nofrows of our tile array
        int nofcol = 0;
        int nofrows = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(path);
        string line = sReader.ReadLine();
        string[] tileNo = line.Split(',');
        nofcol = tileNo.Count();
```

I am trying to read files from the location in 'H:\' drive.

File names are mdata017 , mdata015 , mdata005.
These files contain comma seperated values.
but my code is giving following error.

Also please tell me that the method i m using is correct or not to read this type of data.

Comment: you have a `name[4]` in there, but your array only has 3 elements. maybe you wanted to write `name[i]` instead.

Comment: Code of the function `conairdata` is incomplete. Can you edit your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Name array is of size 3:

```
string[] name = new string[3] {"015", "017", "005"};
```

Where as you are accessing the fifth element at:

```
conairdata(to_date, name[4]);
```

Thats the problem causing code. About your second question whether this is right approach or not.. I am not sure as your function `conairdata` is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

chage your   `conairdata(to_date, name[4]);`

to

`conairdata(to_date, name[3]);`

because **array starts at index from 0**